# How can I make a minimal, unstyled HTML form which works with Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms, html, embed

I want to embed a Google Form in my website, but make it unstyled, etc., so it looks neat and can be placed in widget form.

Comment: Have you [searched](http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms/)?

Comment: @404 I think that the instructions on the referred page are obsolete as they said to use the spreadsheet key instead of the form key.

Comment: @404 at the bottom of the linked article is a section about updates. This looks to be the most recent http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms-redux/

Comment: @gmal how "minimal" is your form? Does it include pages, validations,...? Are you using the old or the new Google Forms?

Answer (score 2):

> UPDATE: This used to work with the old version of Google Forms but it's not available anymore.

## Partial answer

The skeleton of pretty basic instructions will look like the following:

### Get the code

1. Go to http://forms.google.com and create or open a form
2. Go to preview
3. Right click and select view source
4. Copy the source code
5. Paste the source code to a blank local file or to a file in web page editor service.

### Edit the code

Edit the CSS and style parameters of HTML tags.

### Publish the file

Add the file to a web hosting service.

### Emded the file

Use an iframe tag to embed the form.