# Two yes-no questions, if both anwers are yes go to section 2 and 3, will skip section 2

Tags: google-forms

I'll make a survey with Google Forms and add two yes-no questions. If both answers are "yes", they must be navigated to sections 2 and 3 of my survey. Below you could find a scheme:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| ## Section 1                                     |
|                                                  |
|  Question 1:*                                    |
|    ( ) Yes        → Navigation to section 2      |
|    ( ) No         → Continue to next section     |
|                                                  |
|  Question 2:*                                    |
|    ( ) Yes        → Navigation to section 3      |
|    ( ) No         → Continue to next section     |
|                                                  |
----------------------------------------------------
After section 1     → Navigation to section 5       
* Required question
```

Both questions are required. Here are the rules:

```
| Answer question 1 | Answer question 2 | Next section(s)                 |
| ----------------- | ----------------- | ------------------------------- |
| No                | No                | end of survey                   |
| Yes               | No                | Section 2                       |
| No                | Yes               | Section 3                       |
| Yes               | Yes               | First section 2, then section 3 |
```

If one or both sections are done the survey must continue to section 4.

For what I've done see images below or on the first gray box:

[image: one question]
[image: another question]

If I answer with "yes" on both questions, I'll directly go to section 3 and continue to sections 4 and 5. In other words I skip section 2 and that's not what I'll have if question 1 and 2 are "yes".

How could I prevent skipping section 2 if both answers are "yes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "hack" the Google Form as the required feature is not built-in.

> Update: Old forms aren't available anymore

It's worth to say that old forms are easier to hack than the new forms, this because the old basically use "standard" html elements while the new use Google Clousure, an undocumented library.

Regarding "hacking" the olf forms see my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90789/88163) to [How can I make a minimal, unstyled HTML form which works with Google Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90693/how-can-i-make-a-minimal-unstyled-html-form-which-works-with-google-forms/)

Related

- [Conditional required questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/134674/88163)